# Share URL on Facebook without using appId?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'd like to share a URL on Facebook without creating a Facebook app and can also be able to detect if the **"share"** button is pressed. Here is my code:

```
<input type="button" onclick="share_prompt()" value="Share" />

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>    
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
FB.init({
    appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', 
    status: true, 
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true
});

function share_prompt()
{


    FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'share',
    href: 'http://www.mywebsite.com',
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && !response.error_code) {
      alert('Posting completed.');
    } else {
      alert('Error while posting.');
    }
  }
);
 }

</script>
```

With my code the share pop-up shows

> "The parameter app_id is required"

How can I do this? Is it possible? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Why do you not want to create an app id? And why do you need to know if the user shared something?

Comment: @WizKid Im not writing the code for myself.

Comment: So let the person that you write the code for create the app and add you as a developer

Comment: @WizKid That person doesn't know how to do that but never mind. I got the answer. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sharer.php, just open a popup on mouse click:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[encoded-url]
```

You can´t use FB.ui (or FB in general) without an App.